# ListViewItem foreground color base on Binding trigger only for epecific column

Tags: wpf, listview

So this is my Class:

```
public class MyData
{
   public string Name;
   public bool IsOK;
}
```

This is my collection:

```
List<MyData> files;
```

My list view with all y triggers:

```
<ListView
    Name="lvFiles"
    Background="Transparent"
    BorderBrush="Gray"
    BorderThickness="0,0,0,0"
    ItemsSource="{Binding files}"

    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Silver"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                        <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                            <Border x:Name="InnerBorder" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="1">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition MaxHeight="11"/>
                                        <RowDefinition/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <!--<Rectangle x:Name="UpperHighlight" Fill="#75FFFFFF" Visibility="Collapsed"/>-->
                                    <GridViewRowPresenter Grid.RowSpan="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="Gainsboro"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

So here i want to add another `trigger`:

In case my property `IsOK` is `false` i want my `Foreground` color will be `Red`
So i added this:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsOK}" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Salmon" />
</DataTrigger>
```

So this works find but this changed all my column `Foreground` colors and i want to change only this `GridViewColumn`:

```
<GridViewColumn Width="380" Header="File name" >
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image 
                    Width="12"
                    Height="12"
                    x:Name="myImage"
                    Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
                <Image
                    Width="18"
                    Height="18"
                    Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources/pic.ico"
                    Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
                <TextBlock 
                    Text="{Binding File}" ToolTip="{Binding Name}"
                    Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsOK}" Value="False">
                    <Setter TargetName="myImage" Property="Source" Value="pack://application:,,,/Resources/pic2.png"/>
                    <Setter TargetName="myImage" Property="ToolTip" Value="OK"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsOK}" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="myImage" Property="Source" Value="pack://application:,,,/Resources/rfew.png"/>
                    <Setter TargetName="myImage" Property="ToolTip" Value="false"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

Comment: Please see my update

Answer (score 0):

try to use

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

instead of:

```
<Style.Triggers>
```

I'll give you and example:

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
       <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
              <Setter Property="Background" Value="#2D6292"/>
              <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
       </Trigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```